# Automate mapping of dependent properties in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a list of product options each with an sku identifier that is received as JSON from the server. I then have other options which depend on prerequisite values being selected, this is defined by the `requires` array property of the product-option arrays:

```
var serverOptions = [{
    name: "DELL R210",
    price: 100,
    sku: 1001,
},{
    name: "DELL R710",
    price: 200,
    sku: 1002,
},{
    name: "DELL R720 Dual CPU",
    price: 300,
    sku: 1003,
}];

var osOptions = [{
    name: "Windows Standard",
    sku: "201",
    price: 1,
}, {
    name: "Windows Enterprise",
    sku: "202",
    price: 2,
}, {
    name: "CentOS",
    sku: "203",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "Debian",
    sku: "204",
    price: 4,
}];

var databaseOptions = [{
    name: "None",
    sku: "0",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "SQL Express",
    sku: "401",
    requires: ["201", "202"],
    price: 10,
}, {
    name: "SQL Standard",
    sku: "402",
    requires: ["202"],
    price: 5,
}, {
    name: "MySQL",
    sku: "MySQL1",
    requires: ["201", "202", "203"],
    price: 11,
}, {
    name: "RavenDb",
    sku: "403",
    requires: ["203"],
    price: 12,
}, {
    name: "MongoDB",
    sku: "404",
    requires: ["204"],
    price: 13,
}];

var clusterOptions = [{
    name: "None",
    sku: "0",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "Standard MySQL Cluster",
    sku: "4101",
    requires: ["MySQL1"],
    price: 10,
}, {
    name: "Enterprise MS SQL Cluster",
    sku: "4102",
    requires: ["402"],
    price: 5,
}, {
    name: "NoSQL Sharding",
    sku: "4103",
    requires: ["403","404"],
    price: 10,
}];
```

In my viewmodel, I then filter the values available for selection with the following code (generic for the most part, variable references change depending on what is being used to query for the requires checking):

```
self.availableClusteringOptions = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedDbSku = this.selectedDb();

        if (typeof selectedDbSku === "undefined")
            return [];

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.dbClusteringOptions, function (dbCluster) {
            if (typeof dbCluster.requires === "undefined")
                return true;
            else
                return dbCluster.requires && dbCluster.requires.indexOf(selectedDbSku) > -1;
        }, this);
    }, this);
```

Whilst my code works, it is statically typed in advance manually by me and as I add new fields I am doing a lot of copy paste as the code syntax is identical just the variables change (case in point `self.availableDatabases` and `self.availableClusteringOptions`).

In the future we may add in (from the server database) a completely new option object, that would need to be handled, mapped and relationships created, all dynamically. A future product option that could be added could be for example:

```
var managementOptions = [{
    name: "Self managed",
    sku: "0",
    price: "0"
},{
    name: "Windows Management",
    sku: "WindowsManagement",
    price: 1,
    requires: ["201", "202"],
}, {
    name: "Linux Management",
    sku: "LinxManagement",
    requires: ["203", "204"],
    price: 2,
}, {
    name: "Basic Management",
    sku: "ManageAll",
    price: 0,
    requires: ["201", "202","203","204"],
}];
```

This is crying out for automation particularly as this data will be fed from a database, but i don't know where to start with this.

I have seen knockout mapping plugin that will create the viewmodel from json, but from the documentation i am not sure how this would tie in with my data structures as my JSON is a lot more complex than the examples.

How can i automate this code to allow for additional dependent 'requires' prerequisite values to be set dynamically? Can knockout mapping help in this instance or do i need to look at an alternative avenue?

**Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/E54YC/7/**

```
var serverConfig = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.osOptions = osOptions;
    self.dbOptions = databaseOptions;
    self.dbClusteringOptions = clusterOptions;
    self.serverOptions = serverOptions;

    self.selectedServer = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOs = ko.observable();
    self.selectedDb = ko.observable();
    self.selectedDbCluster = ko.observable();

    self.lookupItemForSku = function (lookup, values) {
        if ((typeof lookup != "undefined") && (lookup != "0"))
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(values, function (item) { return item.sku == lookup; }, this);
        else
            return null;
    };

    self.availableDatabases = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedOsSku = this.selectedOs();

        if (typeof selectedOsSku === "undefined")
            return [];

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.dbOptions, function (db) {
            if (typeof db.requires === "undefined")
                return true;
            else
                return db.requires && db.requires.indexOf(selectedOsSku) > -1;
        }, this);
    }, this);

    self.availableClusteringOptions = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedDbSku = this.selectedDb();

        if (typeof selectedDbSku === "undefined")
            return [];

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.dbClusteringOptions, function (dbCluster) {
            if (typeof dbCluster.requires === "undefined")
                return true;
            else
                return dbCluster.requires && dbCluster.requires.indexOf(selectedDbSku) > -1;
        }, this);
    }, this);

    self.availableDatabases.subscribe(function () {
        self.selectedDb(self.availableDatabases()[0].sku);
    });

    self.availableClusteringOptions.subscribe(function () {
        self.selectedDbCluster(self.availableClusteringOptions()[0].sku);
    });

    self.selectedServer(self.serverOptions[0].sku);
    self.selectedOs(self.osOptions[0].sku);

    return self;
};

var configModel = new serverConfig();

ko.applyBindings(configModel);
```

Comment: Be a bit more specific - what do you mean how do you map it?  Do you have a server end point you are hitting and getting some data back from?

Comment: I need to automate this code as much as possible, there is a lot of repetition. From the documentation i believe mapping will create the viewmodel from json, but my case is way more complicated than any of the examples so not sure if it is even possible or i should look for an alternative

Comment: Not to sound like an ass, but the model you are using is extremely lightweight in comparison to how many people use it.  You can either using the mapping plugin or create your own models on the client for re-use.

Comment: The main purpose is to make it dynamic, as the data will be coming from the database. My  question is how to map the `requires` functionality as additional fields are added, this will come in dynamically depending on what is sent from the server as JSON. I have read about ko mapping but i am unsure on how to get started with my code and would greatly appreciate some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick update to your fiddle showing how you could create your own models to map data - http://jsfiddle.net/E54YC/9/

If you wanted to get more intense and have relationship mapping you have many choices, but the top two I would consider -

1. Write your own custom code to handle requirements and whether you can select this or that depending on it's requirements
2. Use a client side data library (ORM) to handle it like Breeze.js where relationship mapping is handled for you and you just need to put the logic in your view model.

Example of a model -

```
function serverModel (server) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(server.name);
    self.Price = ko.observable(server.price);
    self.SKU = ko.observable(server.sku);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PW Kad, so if i understand correctly a better way may be to write our own binding mechanisim? Not sure if its clear, but the actual product-option-types will be dynamic (not just the contents), by that i mean an entirely new product-option array may be sent i.e. managemenOption[]. I will update my question to avoid confusion. Thanks for tip on Breeze, i am new to javascript and such learning is useful

Comment: I have answered your question as best as I can about mapping, if you have an architecture question related to technology you can use or structuring that you have tried and can't find a solution for consider marking this as resolved and creating a new question detailing your problem.  It is not useful to continue chaining questions onto questions that are completely unrelated

Comment: Respectfully my question is and always has been from the start, about dynamically automating the mapping of properties with respect to the filtered available options. Your answer is useful and very much appreciated, but doesn't resolve my question.

Comment: The mapping plugin does just that, it dynamically maps everything.  Not sure how much better of an answer you need : )

Comment: OK I concede :) After sleeping on it and re-reading my question has been answered in that i need to use a mapper. I have had a go with ko.mapper and posted specific questions on that over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447458/handling-arbitary-options-with-metadata-from-server-and-ko-mapping-create-functi

Comment: Just an update to say thank you for giving me a different perspective. I wrote my own simple mapping function that does what i needed, after thinking about your posts it made sense to write the mapping function myself as like you said, it my example wasn't actually complicated mapping metadata. If you get time would appreciate you running your eyes over the code. Thanks again for helping me think outside the box. Code and solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447458/handling-arbitrary-options-with-metadata-from-server-and-ko-mapping-create-funct/19469634#19469634

Comment: Sure I will look at it today or Monday