# Handling arbitrary options with metadata from server and ko.mapping create function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a view-model where some properties values available for selection are dictated by other properties, this is set via the `requires` field:

```
var clusterOptions = [{
    name: "None",
    sku: "0",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "Standard MySQL Cluster",
    sku: "4101",
    requires: ["MySQL1"],
    price: 10,
}, {
    name: "Enterprise MS SQL Cluster",
    sku: "4102",
    requires: ["402"],
    price: 5,
}, {
    name: "NoSQL Sharding",
    sku: "4103",
    requires: ["403","404"],
    price: 10,
}];
```

The code works (you can see how clicking different options changes dependent options `database` and `database clustering`): **http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/DTdyM/**

This code is statically typed, and i am trying to convert this so that arbitrary data (and requires mappings) can be sent from the server viewmodel created with `ko.mapping`.

The code to calculate available options for selection is in a helper function (example shown below for two dependent properties from my initial statically defined example):

```
self.availableDatabases = myutils.ko.createComputedDepdency(this.selectedOs, this.dbOptions);
self.availableClusteringOptions = myutils.ko.createComputedDepdency(this.selectedDb, this.dbClusteringOptions);
```

I have rewritten my serverData and the only things i need to know form my model are the selected items of the arrays passed in dynamically from the server, in this case it is the options array: `selectedServerOption`, `selectedOsOption`, `selectedDatabaseOption` and `selectedClusterOption`

I am stuck handling the mapping and unsure how to work with the `requiresMapping` array.

How can I handle the mapping of the option fields below?

```
var serverData = {
    options: [serverOptions, osOptions, databaseOptions, clusterOptions],

    requiresMappings: [
        {target: "selectedOs", options: "dbOptions"},
        {target: "selectedDb", options: "dbClusteringOptions"}
    ]
}

var mappingScheme = {
    'options' : {
        create: function(options){
            console.log("creating sku: " + options.data.sku);
            // 1) create dependency using requiresMappings property
            // myutils.ko.createComputedDepdency(this.selectedOs, this.dbOptions);

            // 2) subscribe to updates
            // self.availableDatabases.subscribe(function () {self.selectedDb(self.availableDatabases()[0].sku);});
        }
    },
    // ignore these mappings we don't want to observe them, they are used to define mappings for the creation function above
    'ignore' : ["requiresMappings"]
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, mappingScheme);
```

**My current fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/DTdyM/5/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing [Automate mapping of dependent properties in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434411/automate-mapping-of-dependent-properties-in-knockout) answer and the code from @PW Kad, it made sense to write a simple custom mapper.

I chose to write my own mapper over ko.mapping as i couldn't work out how to reference the mapping for the requires (with ko.mapping), and in particular how to make multiple properties from the `create` mapping function (as i could see i could only return a single new property, not multiple as i would need).

It works seemingly well, but would appreciate comments or an alternative using ko.mapping just to help my understanding especially if i have reinvented the wheel!

[Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/DTdyM/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/DTdyM/26/)

```
var myutils = myutils || {}; // if namespace is not defined, make it equal to an empty object

myutils.ko = (function(){
    var createComputedDepdency = function(targetDependency, options){
        var computedProperty = ko.computed(function(){
            var targetValue = targetDependency();

            if(typeof targetValue === "undefined")
                return [];

            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(options, function(opt){
                if(typeof opt.requires === "undefined")
                    return true;
                else
                    return opt.requires && opt.requires.indexOf(targetValue) > -1;
            });
        });        
        return computedProperty;
    };

    var createProductViewModel = function(options){

        var viewModel = {};      
        var length = options.length; 

        console.log(length);

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var option = options[i];

            console.log("creating property: " + option.selectedName + ", options: " + option.optionsName);

            // create the property for selected value, i.e. object.firstName = ko.observable();
            viewModel[option.selectedName] = ko.observable();

            if(option.requires)
            {
                var computedOptions = createComputedDepdency(viewModel[option.requires.target],option.data);
                viewModel[option.optionsName] = computedOptions;

                console.log("making callback scope object for: " + option.optionsName );
                var callbackScope = {
                    callbackName: option.optionsName,
                    options: computedOptions,
                    selectedValue: viewModel[option.selectedName]
                };

                // when the list of available options changes, set the selected property to the first option
                computedOptions.subscribe(function () {
                    var scope = this;
                    console.log("my object: %o", scope);   
                    scope.selectedValue(scope.options()[0].sku);
                    console.log("in subscribe function for..." + scope.callbackName);
                },callbackScope);
            }
            else
            {
                // create the property holding values, i.e. object.nameOptions = serverData.names;
                viewModel[option.optionsName] = option.data; 
            } 
        }

        // now all options have been created, loop through the array one last time and set the dependent options.
        // note that this should be done last, as dependent calculated properties will subscribed to these events
        // and update their default first options
        for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            var option = options[x];

            // only need to do this to non-calculated values
            if(!option.requires)
            {
                viewModel[option.selectedName](viewModel[option.optionsName][0].sku);
            }
        }

        return viewModel;
    };

    return{
        createProductViewModel: createProductViewModel
    };
}());

var serverOptions = [{
    name: "DELL R210",
    price: 100,
    sku: 1001,
},{
    name: "DELL R710",
    price: 200,
    sku: 1002,
},{
    name: "DELL R720 Dual CPU",
    price: 300,
    sku: 1003,
}];

var osOptions = [{
    name: "Windows Standard",
    sku: "201",
    price: 1,
}, {
    name: "Windows Enterprise",
    sku: "202",
    price: 2,
}, {
    name: "CentOS",
    sku: "203",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "Debian",
    sku: "204",
    price: 4,
}];

var databaseOptions = [{
    name: "None",
    sku: "0",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "SQL Express",
    sku: "401",
    requires: ["201", "202"],
    price: 10,
}, {
    name: "SQL Standard",
    sku: "402",
    requires: ["202"],
    price: 5,
}, {
    name: "MySQL",
    sku: "MySQL1",
    requires: ["201", "202", "203"],
    price: 11,
}, {
    name: "RavenDb",
    sku: "403",
    requires: ["203"],
    price: 12,
}, {
    name: "MongoDB",
    sku: "404",
    requires: ["204"],
    price: 13,
}];

var databaseClusterOptions = [{
    name: "None",
    sku: "0",
    price: 0,
}, {
    name: "Standard MySQL Cluster",
    sku: "4101",
    requires: ["MySQL1"],
    price: 10,
}, {
    name: "Enterprise MS SQL Cluster",
    sku: "4102",
    requires: ["402"],
    price: 5,
}, {
    name: "NoSQL Sharding",
    sku: "4103",
    requires: ["403","404"],
    price: 10,
}];

var serverData = {
    options: [
        { data: serverOptions, selectedName: "selectedServer", optionsName: "serverOptions" },
        { data: osOptions, selectedName: "selectedOs", optionsName: "osOptions" },
        { data: databaseOptions, selectedName: "selectedDb", optionsName: "availableDatabases", requires: { target: "selectedOs" } },
        { data: databaseClusterOptions, selectedName: "selectedDbCluster", optionsName: "availableClusteringOptions", requires: { target: "selectedDb" } }
    ]
};

var viewModel = myutils.ko.createProductViewModel(serverData.options);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```